# Docker Confluent Kafka HDFS Sink Running but Task Failed

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using the Confluent Kafka [all-in-one docker image](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/tree/master/examples/cp-all-in-one) to setup Kafka on a DigitalOcean droplet. I am able to successfully run Kafka and add the HDFS connector using the Kafka Connect REST API. I replace HOST_IP with my [Cloudera CDH](https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/quickstart/) droplet's IP.

```
 curl -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{
  "name": "hdfs-sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "test_hdfs",
    "hdfs.url": "hdfs://HOST_IP:8020",
    "flush.size": "3",
    "name": "hdfs-sink"
  }}' \
  http://HOST_IP:8083/connectors
```

Then when I curl Kafka Connect for the hdfs-sink status, I receive the following error in the JSON response under task (the status of the service is running but the task has failed):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy is not an instance of io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.SubjectNameStrategy

**UPDATE**
So I managed to overcome this error by using 5.0.0 rather than the beta (silly me) as recommended by cricket007.

However, I'm receiving a different error when I actually attempt to publish data to my HDFS instance. I am using the ksql-datagen in order to generate fake data

`docker-compose exec ksql-datagen ksql-datagen quickstart=users format=json topic=test_hdfs maxInterval=1000 \ propertiesFile=/etc/ksql/datagen.properties bootstrap-server=broker:9092`

```
{
    "name": "hdfs-sink",
    "connector": {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "worker_id": "connect:8083"
    },
    "tasks": [{
        "state": "FAILED",
        "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:510)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:490)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:225)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: test_hdfs\n\tat io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:97)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$0(WorkerSinkTask.java:510)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)\n\t... 13 more\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!\n",
        "id": 0,
        "worker_id": "connect:8083"
    }],
    "type": "sink"
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Stack Trace for Avro ksql-datagen failing

```
Outputting 1000000 to test_hdfs
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing row to topic test_hdfs using Converter API
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: test_hdfs
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:77)
    at io.confluent.ksql.serde.connect.KsqlConnectSerializer.serialize(KsqlConnectSerializer.java:44)
    at io.confluent.ksql.serde.connect.KsqlConnectSerializer.serialize(KsqlConnectSerializer.java:27)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:854)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:816)
    at io.confluent.ksql.datagen.DataGenProducer.populateTopic(DataGenProducer.java:94)
    at io.confluent.ksql.datagen.DataGen.main(DataGen.java:100)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:172)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:229)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:320)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:312)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:307)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:114)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:153)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:79)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Serializer.serialize(AvroConverter.java:116)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:75)
    at io.confluent.ksql.serde.connect.KsqlConnectSerializer.serialize(KsqlConnectSerializer.java:44)
    at io.confluent.ksql.serde.connect.KsqlConnectSerializer.serialize(KsqlConnectSerializer.java:27)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:854)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:816)
    at io.confluent.ksql.datagen.DataGenProducer.populateTopic(DataGenProducer.java:94)
    at io.confluent.ksql.datagen.DataGen.main(DataGen.java:100)
```

**EDIT 3**

Ok so for some reason even though I am generating avro data with ksql-datagen I am still receiving a JSON serialization error on Kafka Connect.

`docker-compose exec ksql-datagen ksql-datagen schema=/impressions.avro format=avro schemaRegistryUrl=http://schema-registry:8081 key=impressionid topic=test_hdfs maxInterval=1000 \ propertiesFile=/etc/ksql/datagen.properties bootstrap-server=broker:9092`

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{
  "name": "hdfs-sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
    "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.avro.AvroFormat",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "schema.compatibility": "FULL",
    "topics": "test_hdfs",
    "hdfs.url": "hdfs://cdh.nuvo.app:8020",
    "flush.size": "3",
    "name": "hdfs-sink"
  }}' \
  http://kafka.nuvo.app:8083/connectors
```

Schema Registry Config

```
# Bootstrap Kafka servers. If multiple servers are specified, they should be comma-separated.
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# The converters specify the format of data in Kafka and how to translate it into Connect data.
# Every Connect user will need to configure these based on the format they want their data in
# when loaded from or stored into Kafka
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081

# The internal converter used for offsets and config data is configurable and must be specified,
# but most users will always want to use the built-in default. Offset and config data is never
# visible outside of Connect in this format.
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

Kafka Connect Log:

```
  org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:510)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:490)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:225)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:193)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error: 
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:334)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$0(WorkerSinkTask.java:510)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'impression_816': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (byte[])"impression_816"; line: 1, column: 29]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'impression_816': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (byte[])"impression_816"; line: 1, column: 29]
```

**EDIT 4**

```
[2018-08-22 02:05:51,140] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:510)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:490)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:225)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:193)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: test_hdfs1
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$0(WorkerSinkTask.java:510)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
[2018-08-22 02:05:51,141] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-sink-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
[2018-08-22 02:05:51,243] INFO Publish thread interrupted for client_id=consumer-8 client_type=CONSUMER session= cluster=lUWD_PR0RsiTkaunoUrUfA group=connect-hdfs-sink (io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringInterceptor)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? It might be that you have to get it from the connect logs, not the rest api

Comment: Sounds like you have a conflicting version of this class https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/subject/TopicNameStrategy.java

Comment: Those linked compose files have not been updated yet for 5.0.0 release, and still say beta. Please use a release version

Comment: @dawsaw Will post a full stack trace tomorrow.

Comment: @cricket_007 will try with a supported release version tomorrow.

Comment: @cricket_007 Updated the versions and that error disappeared :) but another got another one when attempting to write to HDFS.

Comment: `Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!`... This means either your Kafka message key or value where not serialized as Avro (using the Confluent Schema Registry) and you have setup the `AvroConveter` in your Connect properties.

Answer (score 1):

You set `ksql-datagen ... format=json`

But the error indicates you have setup the AvroConverter in Kafka Connect

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
```

Look at your Compose file...

```
  CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
  CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
  CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
  CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
```

If you want to produce Avro data **instead** [refer to the `ksql-datagen` docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/tutorials/generate-custom-test-data.html).

And although you are producing JSON, currently, that's not what will be put on HDFS with your configuration.
Avro is the default *output format* for HDFS Connect; if you refer to the [configuration documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/configuration_options.html#connector).

> `format.class`
>   The format class to use when writing data to the
>   store. Format classes implement the
>   `io.confluent.connect.storage.format.Format` interface.
>
> Type: class
>   Default: `io.confluent.connect.hdfs.avro.AvroFormat`
>   Importance: high
>
> These classes are available by default:
>
> - `io.confluent.connect.hdfs.avro.AvroFormat`
> - `io.confluent.connect.hdfs.json.JsonFormat`
> - `io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetFormat`
> - `io.confluent.connect.hdfs.string.StringFormat`

If you don't use JsonFormat, I believe in order to output Avro from JSON [you need a JSON record that looks like so](https://rmoff.net/2017/09/06/kafka-connect-jsondeserializer-with-schemas-enable-requires-schema-and-payload-fields/)

```
{
  "schema": {...}
  "payload": {...}
}
```

Otherwise, an Avro schema cannot be inferred from a JSON record.

---

Through your series of edits I think you switched to producing Avro, but using JsonConverter based on what I mentioned above, which isn't what I was suggesting. Basically, the Converter class type must match the producer data and defines the consumer deserializer

For the serialization error with id -1, it's basically saying that the data either in the key or the value is not Avro. Now, KSQL doesn't quite work with Avro keys, so I'd wager its the key deserializer that's failing. To address that issue, set

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
```

Comment: @cricket007 I made progress on this by using ksql-datagen with Avro format messages but I am running into an issue
`
docker-compose exec ksql-datagen ksql-datagen schema=/impressions.avro format=avro key=impressionid topic=test_hdfs maxInterval=1000 \ propertiesFile=/etc/ksql/datagen.properties bootstrap-server=broker:9092
`
`Outputting 1000000 to test_hdfs
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing row to topic test_hdfs using Converter API` 

See edit 2

Comment: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`... Your Schema Registry is not functional, or you never ran one.

Comment: Oh, on `ksql-datagen`, if you pass `format=avro`, then you need to pass `schemaRegistryUrl=http://schema-registry:8081`

Comment: @cricket007 I'm still receiving a JSON parse error even though I've specified Avro everywhere. Only thing I'm thinking is something to do with the internal 
# The internal converter used for offsets and config data is configurable and must be specified,

See above Edit 3

Comment: Well 1) I see `JsonConverter` in your logs, but that shouldn't be part of your Compose file. 2) `byte[]` data is not a JSON type. Ultimately, I don't know what data is in your topic originally, but Connect is trying to read bytes from Kafka topic, then ultimately parse it somehow. If you generated Avro data, then you must use the AvroConverter. What you can change is `format.class` in the HDFS Connect configuration

Comment: Seems like I am missing something again. I fixed the       CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'

but I'm still receiving the Avro serialization error.

Comment: So, now I bet the issue is that your keys are not Avro. Remove the registry line for only the key and use `org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter` for the key converter